# Javafx TableView data refresh

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have combobox, tableview as `TableView<Person>` and 3 columns. 
I want to populate the updated data in `TableView` as per item I select in combobox.

My Issue: every time I select the item in combobox, the data in table view is added. I want the details to be displayed for the selected item only.

Code:

```
public class MyTableController {

    private TableView<Person> personTableView;
    private ObservableList<Person> personTableViewData= FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    initialize() {
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                List<Person> filteredPersonList = 
                               personList.stream().filter(person -> person.getFirstName().contains(newValue)).collect(Collectors.toList());

                personTableViewData.addAll(filteredPersonList);
                personTableView.setItems(personTableViewData);

            } 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ObservableList.setAll` instead of `ObservableList.addAll` or alternatively create a new `ObservableList`. Otherwise you're adding new items to the same list on every change instead of replacing the items:

```
initialize() {
    personTableView.setItems(personTableViewData);

    comboBox.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            List<Person> filteredPersonList = 
                           personList.stream().filter(person -> person.getFirstName().contains(newValue)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            personTableViewData.setAll(filteredPersonList);
        } 
    }
```